# How to make Linux shell command stack store only unique commands

Tags: linux, shell, stack

I just reformated my HD and had to overwrite my /home partition. Everything is fine in Linux Mint 11.

Except that the command stack recall with cursor up/down displays repeats of the same command.

Like:

```
ls
ls
ls
cd ~

should be:

ls
cd ~
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using bash.

Add this to to your `~/.bashrc`

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using bash:

```
export HISTIGNORE="&"
```